# Change file names iteratively in Linux

Tags: linux, bash

The only way I am aware of to do this operation is with a for loop iterating over each file:

```
for file in *something.txt; do  
    out=\`echo $file | sed 's/something/else/'\`;  mv $file $out;  
done
```

I was wondering if there is any other way or shortcut for it (using GNU bash).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is also simple **substring replacement** provided as part of bash itself:

```
mv $file ${file/something/else}
```

**example:**

```
$ touch {1..3}something.txt
$ ( for i in *something.txt; do mv $i ${i/something/else}; done )
$ ls -1 *else*
1else.txt
2else.txt
3else.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

There's [rename](http://linux.die.net/man/2/rename) and the same basic loop concept as in your post only in whatever programming language you choose.

Comment: great, I was looking for something like this